# Why Fortran 90 code is not well supported in R?

Tags: r, fortran, rcpp

Despite that the Writing R Extensions manual mentions f90/f95. It seems that it is not well supported, especially it is mixed with C++.

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2015-March/070851.html

But if I have to use f90/f95 code with Rcpp. Is there a walkaround currently available? Thanks.

Comment: The place you found that post -- the r-devel mailing list -- would be the best place to ask that question.

Comment: So if you have to use f90/f95 code, do you have to mix it with c++? What is the specific thing you are trying to code? This isn't a very specific question that can be easily answered.

Comment: did you try it? I have not had problems. A walk-around for what, your question indicates that you haven't started

Comment: "- Free source form Fortran 9x is not portable." -> Seems they just don't know modern Fortran and its portability features.

Comment: For the `.Fortran` function in R, you have to call a Fortran subroutine that only looks like a Fortran77 subroutine: Not hidden in a module, no allocatable arrays, only the F77 types  (`real`, `character`, `integer`; but `double` does work, too). Besides this, you can code what you want; mix C, use Fortran2003 features, etc.

Answer (score 5):

(I think I just answer I [rather similar question on rcpp-devel](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.rcpp/8466).)

Citing from [Writing R Extensions, Section 1.1.5](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Package-subdirectories) with my use of bold face below:

> The sources and headers for the compiled code are in src, plus
>   optionally a file Makevars or Makefile. When a package is installed
>   using R CMD INSTALL, make is used to control compilation and linking
>   into a shared object for loading into R. There are default make
>   variables and rules for this (determined when R is configured and
>   recorded in R_HOME/etcR_ARCH/Makeconf), providing support for C, C++,
>   FORTRAN 77, Fortran 9x15, Objective C and Objective C++16 with
>   associated extensions .c, .cc or .cpp, .f, .f90 or .f95, .m, and .mm,
>   respectively. We recommend using .h for headers, also for C++17 or
>   Fortran 9x include files. (Use of extension .C for C++ is no longer
>   supported.) Files in the src directory should not be hidden (start
>   with a dot), and hidden files will under some versions of R be
>   ignored.
>
> It is not portable (and may not be possible at all) to mix all these
>   languages in a single package, **and we do not support using both C++
>   and Fortran 9x**. Because R itself uses it, we know that C and FORTRAN
>   77 can be used together and mixing C and C++ seems to be widely
>   successful.

You would have to ask R Core why they chose to outlaw this.  Usually, this means some technical reason.  I do not use Fortran so I can't help with th reasoning behind it.